# Is there a subquery that can use a max date from a different column in the same table to calculate datediff?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to create a MySQL query that will look at a column, identify the most recent date in that column, and then use that date in date difference calculations to create new columns.

I have already tried to use a WHERE statement to create a new maxdate to use instead of Now() in datediff calculations but that just gives me one record containing the OLDEST record in my table, which is the datediff with the largest difference.

```
SELECT 
    table.firstname
    table.first_order_day
    table.last_order_day
    DATEDIFF(MAX(last_order_day),first_order_day) AS "Customer Tenure"
    DATEDIFF(MAX(last_order_day),last_order_day) AS "Days Since Last Order"
FROM table
```

Expected/DESIRED result (MaxDate taken from last_order_day column:  2019-09-01):

```
first name,first_order_day,last_order_day,Customer Tenure,Days Since Last Order

Andrew,2019-01-01, 2019-05-01, 243, 123
Audrey,2019-02-01, 2019-09-01, 212, 0
Matt,2019-03-01, 2019-06-01, 184, 92

Actual output:
Audrey,2019-02-01, 2019-09-01, 212, 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    table.firstname
    table.first_order_day
    table.last_order_day
    DATEDIFF((SELECT MAX(last_order_day) FROM table),first_order_day) AS "Customer Tenure"
    DATEDIFF((SELECT MAX(last_order_day) FROM table),last_order_day) AS "Days Since Last Order"
FROM table
```

Answer (score 2):

You can `JOIN` a subquery that computes the max:

```
SELECT 
    t.firstname
    t.first_order_day
    t.last_order_day
    DATEDIFF(x.last_order_day, t.first_order_day) AS "Customer Tenure"
    DATEDIFF(x.last_order_day, t.last_order_day) AS "Days Since Last Order"
FROM 
    mytable t
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT MAX(t.last_order_day) last_order_day FROM mytable) x
```

Or, if you run MySQL 8.0, you may also use a window function:

```
SELECT 
    firstname
    first_order_day
    last_order_day
    DATEDIFF(MAX(last_order_day) OVER(), first_order_day) AS "Customer Tenure"
    DATEDIFF(MAX(last_order_day) OVER(), last_order_day) AS "Days Since Last Order"
FROM 
    mytable
```

Comment: Note that `last_order_day` is ambiguous. So yo need to use a table prefix or rename it in the subquery. Also you can't use `table.*` when you have aliased the table with `t`.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel: thanks for your comment, I fixed the query.

Comment: BTW: Even with MySQL 8 I would prefer the first query. One reason is that it's not clear, if the engine can optimize and evaluate `MAX(last_order_day) OVER()` only once. While this is clear for the derived table.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel: seems like the expression is simple enough for the optimizer to do factorization, but who knows? I agree that the first query is clearer and won't be less performant, so it is probably better anyway.

Comment: For the first query, I wasn't able to recreate the coding since I wasn't clear what table to use for x.last_order_day.  Let's assume the t.firstname is actually a table called info.  What table is used in the cross join to connect to?

Comment: @LeighAG: there is actually a single table involved the query, which appears twice. You can replace both occurences of `mytable` with the name of your table.